# Android ndk : ACameraManager_getCameraIdList return 0

Tags: camera, native, android-source, legacy

I have an Android 8.1 rk3399 board with an OV13850 camera module.

This module's interface is mipi-csi and protocol is I2C.

When I log the camera characteristics, it was CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY.

I really really want to use an ndk camera.

But people say that the native camera does not support legacy.

**Question 1:**

I have a Raspberry b+ mipi camera.

If I simply change the camera module, would it be compatible?

I think the interfaces are the same, so there is no need to edit board SDK code.

Just adding to the .rc file might work.

**Question 2:**

I want to support legacy camera on the native side.

If I edit some code on the ndk framework code and build my own.m, would it be possible to support legacy?

**Question 3:**

Which part decides if the camera module is legacy or not (physical module, module's kernel driver, Android OS camera code, ndk framework, etc.)?

What method should I choose between changing physical camera module or editing code for native processing?

Question 4:

What is different between the legacy camera and full camera?

Comment: Those are four really broad questions. Please try to narrow research yourself and narrow them down to new, individual questions concerning individual programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can modify the framework to have some support for a LEGACY camera2 without Java. See my [POC](https://github.com/alexcohn/native-camera2) that backports the NDK Camera2 support to Android 6, you will need to cherry pick some changes. My code does work with LEGACY camera, but I never tested it beyond the very basic functionality.

You cannot run my code as is on Android 8, because it forbids linking the system libraries from user code.

The [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics) describe in detail what limitations LEGACY camera has, but TL;NR: LEGACY camera has an old camera HAL and some wrapper that emulates camera2 API to the user apps. The rule of thumb is to use the old *deprecated* Camera API when you detect a LEGACY camera, this way you avoid some extra wrappers and bugs therein.

Unfortunately, this cannot help your cause because the our Camera does not have public C++ API. Also, I don't think changing the camera module can help. The LEGACY nature of the camera is determined on the level of firmware.